# Active Directory - Join domain in specific OU when its a workstation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

I would like to know how can I accomplish the following:

When I join a workstation (with Windows 7) in the domain, I want that computer to be put into a specific OU. Only when its a workstation with Windows 7. This is because I have GPOs that must apply to all workstations in the domain.

Can I only accomplish this using a script? Or can I set a rule like if the computers has Windows 7, put that computer into this specific OU.

Comment: Where would you like this rule to run on?

Comment: Do you want the *all* to go to the same OU or would some go to a different OU?

Comment: I just want all employees workstations on the same OU, non-workstations on a different OU.

Comment: Are these new image deployment? If so, you could look at using MDT to deploy the image and set it up to join to that specific OU.

Answer (score 6):

By default all computers joined to the domain will go the `Computers` container, unless you pre-stage a computer object in a specific OU.  You could modify this by changing the default path for computer objects using `redircmp.exe` (found in %SYSTEMROOT%\System32).  For example:

```
redircmp OU=win7,DC=company,DC=com
```

This would change the default path to the `Win7` OU, under the root of the domain.

See [Redirecting the users and computers containers in Active Directory domains](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324949) for more info.

You could specify your OU for the Windows 7 machines as the default, then if needed, pre-stage any workstations/servers you don't want in the Windows 7 machine OU elsewhere.

Our you could simply move the objects to the required OUs after they've been joined to the domain and wait for GPO processing to re-occur.

Comment: Cant I redirect computers to specific OUs based on their OS current ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Why not just pre-create the computer objects in the proper OU THEN join to the domain?